I need to make the loop end in RSCPU
JUMP Start
A: DB 07    ; Input number (binary to count 1's)
C: DB 00    ; Counter for the number of 1's

Start:
    CLAC        ; Clear AC to initialize the counter (C = 0)
    STAC C      ; Store 0 into C

BitCheckLoop:
    LDAC A      ; Load A into AC
    MVAC
    CLAC   ; Isolate the current bit of A
    INAC
    AND
    LDAC C      ; Load the current count of 1's
    INAC        ; Increment the count
    STAC C      ; Store the updated count in C
    CLAC
    INAC
    INAC
    MVAC
    LDAC A
    AND
    LDAC C      ; Load the current count of 1's
    INAC        ; Increment the count
    STAC C      ; Store the updated count in C

    JMPZ End    ; If c has exceeded valid bits, end loop

    JUMP BitCheckLoop ; Repeat the loop

End:
    JUMP End    ; End the program

